# Gulp Sass Compile Issue

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

My Gulp SCSS Compiler below works fine with single files, and when including files into a single output e.g. styles.scss & _base.scss which would output styles.css.

However if I was two output files e.g. styles.css & base.css upon making the scss file 'base.scss' it complies it to the dest still with the .scss extension. Its not till I actually rerun the compile task till I get a base.css file as well as the base.scss file in the dest folder...

```
gulp.task('build-css', function() {
    return gulp.src('source/scss/**/*.scss', { style: 'expanded' })
        .pipe(plugins.sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public_html/css'));
});
```

Im using node-sass. I do not want to use ruby-sass

Output in public_html/css/

What I'm getting

```
css/
- base.scss
- base.css
- style.css
```

what I want to get

```
css/
- base.css
- style.css
```

Answer (score 1):

You are putting `{ style: 'expanded' }` in the incorrect location of the function. Your function should look like this instead:

```
gulp.task('build-css', function() {
    return gulp.src('source/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(plugins.sass({ style: 'expanded' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public_html/css'));
});
```

Comment: ++ its `outputStyle: expanded` not `style: 'expanded'`: https://github.com/sass/node-sass

Answer (score 0):

There is no such an option as `{ style: 'expanded' }` available in for `gulp.src`

To control the output style, you need to specify [outputStyle](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#outputstyle) and pass it as an argument with `plugins.sass(options)` call.